# React cannot read object of custom js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have database in .js file with objects like

```
var cards = {
devil: {
    index: '1',
    name: 'Дьявол',
    image: 'img/cards/devil.png',
    meaning: 'devil meaning',
    shortMeaning: 'shortmeaning'
},
death: {
    index: '2',
    name: 'смерть',
    image: 'img/cards/death.png',
    meaning: 'death meaning',
    shortMeaning: 'death shortmeaning'
}
};
```

And I imported this Db.js with webpack on the server:
`import {cards, cardqueue, cardback} from './Db.js';` 
Previously I tested it with using  tag and it worked fine. But now I get this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at image={this.state.firstCard.image}
Here's part of the code

```
class Deck extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  firstCard: cardback,
  secondCard: cardback,
  thirdCard: cardback,
  fourthCard: cardback,
  fifthCard: cardback,
  sixthCard: cardback,
  seventhCard: cardback,
  rolledCards: [],
  reloadAnimation: false,
  cardAnswer: cardqueue,
  cardDetails: 8
};
// This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
handleClick() {
let cardsArray = ['chariot','death','devil','emperor','empress','fool','hangedman','hermit','hierophant','highpriestess','judgment','justice','lovers','magician','moon','star','strength','sun','temperance','tower','wheeloffortune','world',];
shuffle(cardsArray);
let arrayvar = this.state.rolledCards.slice();  arrayvar.push(cardsArray[0],cardsArray[1],cardsArray[2],cardsArray[3],cardsArray[4],cardsArray[5],cardsArray[6]);
this.setState({ 
  arrayvar: arrayvar, 
  firstCard: cards[arrayvar[0]], 
  secondCard: cards[arrayvar[1]],
  thirdCard: cards[arrayvar[2]],
  fourthCard: cards[arrayvar[3]],
  fifthCard: cards[arrayvar[4]],
  sixthCard: cards[arrayvar[5]],
  seventhCard: cards[arrayvar[6]],
  cardDetails: 8
});
this.setState(prevState => ({
  reloadAnimation: !prevState.reloadAnimation
}));
}
render() {
return (
  <div className="deck-container">
    <div id="deck-flipped">
      <DeckItem onClick={this.handleClick}></DeckItem>
    </div>
    <div className="chosen-cards">
      <CardHistory 
        className={this.state.reloadAnimation ? 'card animated flipInY' : 'card animated reload-flipInY'} 
        name={this.state.firstCard.name} 
        image={this.state.firstCard.image} 
        meaning={this.state.firstCard.meaning}
        cardqueueItem={this.state.cardAnswer.first.answer}
        cardDetails={this.state.cardDetails}
        onClick={() => this.showCardDetails(0)}
      />
      {
        this.state.cardDetails==0 
          ? <CardDetails 
              image={this.state.firstCard.image} 
              answer={this.state.cardAnswer.first.answer} 
              name={this.state.firstCard.name} 
              meaning={this.state.firstCard.meaning}
              shortMeaning={this.state.firstCard.shortMeaning}
              onClick={this.closeCardDetails} 
            />
          : null
        }
   </div>
</div>
);
}
}
```

By default `firstCard` state contains a `cardback` string and `handleClick()` changes it to cards[arrayvar[0]], and then I get property 'name' of object 'cards[arrayvar[0]]' by firstCard.name but now it returns undefined. Why does it happen? It works fine in my text-editor with using `script` tag but nothing here.

Comment: In your handleClick, try log `arrayvar[0]` out before `setState`. What will that be?

Comment: It always random, works how it should work.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: It returns a random object inside cards

Comment: I mean it works only on my PC, where I used `script` tag. Page doesnt renders on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using ES6, you can export/import the following way:

**Importing**

```
import {cards, cardqueue, cardback} from './Db.js';
```

**Exporting**

You would need to export these modules in your `DB.js` file like this:

```
export const cards = {
devil: {
    index: '1',
    name: 'Дьявол',
    image: 'img/cards/devil.png',
    meaning: 'devil meaning',
    shortMeaning: 'shortmeaning'
},
death: {
    index: '2',
    name: 'смерть',
    image: 'img/cards/death.png',
    meaning: 'death meaning',
    shortMeaning: 'death shortmeaning'
}
};

// export the other constants here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `module.exports= (the object)` Otherwise the imported object will be blank ^^

Or

```
var cards = {
devil: {
    index: '1',
    name: 'Дьявол',
    image: 'img/cards/devil.png',
    meaning: 'devil meaning',
    shortMeaning: 'shortmeaning'
},
death: {
    index: '2',
    name: 'смерть',
    image: 'img/cards/death.png',
    meaning: 'death meaning',
    shortMeaning: 'death shortmeaning'
}
};
module.exports = cards;
```

Comment: I tried `module.exports` but I get the same error but now it cannot find property of answer. :> I get my objects randomly, how can I export this right?

Comment: You might have to change `import {cards, cardqueue, cardback} from './Db.js';` to `import {devil,death} from './Db.js';`

Comment: I dont see the import statement provided in the code snippet. :(

Comment: Make sure you understand Destructuring assignment and Js modules. ^^ Lots of documentation out there.

Comment: It requires cards, cardback and cardqueue then.